# Am I allowed to have one button with two actions in one for-loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any reason I shouldn't do this? I'm fairly new at programming iPhone so I just want to check that its not making my memory footprint really high for some reason or anything like that.

I'm creating buttons in a loop (one for each letter in a phrase) and then there may be up to about 100 instances of this code running simultaneously so if there's a problem with it it could be a big problem.

Thanks for the advice!

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[aButton setTag:l];
CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(11+charact*20, -40 + line*50, 18, 21);
aButton.frame = buttonRect;

[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(thisButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[aButton setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[gameScroll addSubview:aButton];
```

Comment: whats the reason to have 2 click events for same button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're registering 2 different selectors for same events type. What will happen - the second one will override the first one. What is the point of this? May be you have a typo in your code sample, but anyway, you can register different selectors for different events. And if you're creating your buttons in the loop it's not a problem, since each time it will register a different object for this target. Your function will look like this probably:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
   // your code
}
```

where the `sender` is the object, which sends the selector to a target. In this case your button.

As for them running simultaneously... Do they run on different threads? Usually GUI runs only on main thread, so it will not happen simultaneously if this is a concern.

Hope it answers your question

Comment: what do you mean the second selector will override the first one? as in only one of the methods will be called? they both seem to run ok... sorry im a noober with objective C

Comment: I wrote that they are for same type of events: UIControlEventTouchUpInside. For same button you can have only one selector for one type of events. Second selector for same type will override the first one.

Comment: the name of the function. Like buttonClicked: and thisButton:. 2 these selectors(functions) were registered for same click event. But it's impossible, so when you will click on your button only thisButton: function will be performed (the last you've registered)

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningful to have multiple actions for different types of control events.

For same control event, those different actions would get invoked. Are you going to do same task in those different actions?

If you want to do different task in those different actions, cannot you do the same using some condition in the only one same action?